# bin/magento command broken after 2.4.1. upgrade because of missing Magento\MediaGallerySynchronizationApi\Model\ImportFilesInterface

Tags: magento2, upgrade

bin/magento command broken after 2.4.1. upgrade because of missing Magento\MediaGallerySynchronizationApi\Model\ImportFilesInterface

we are not excluding or replacing anthing related to MediaGallerySynchronizationApi in composer

Why can this be happening? and how to solve it?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\MediaGallerySynchronizationApi\Model\ImportFilesInterface in /home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#1 /home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#2 /home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#3 /home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#4 /home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php in /home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had pretty same issue. The reason of issue was redis cache, in my case it was enough to comment cache related config in file `app/etc/env.php`

```php
'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
...
```

or run commands via CLI or in update script (replace ports and db numbers wit correct)

```
  redis-cli -p 6379 -n 1 flushdb > /dev/null      # Flush session db
  redis-cli -p 6380 -n 1 flushdb > /dev/null      # Flush cache db
  redis-cli -p 6380 -n 2 flushdb > /dev/null      # Flush page  db
```

and after that run all required commands then enable it again.

Comment: Cool. I have a flush statement for that somewhere.  Let me check when behind laptop